# tslm model - how to include many variables(100s) using newdata agrument

Tags: r

I have to incorporate more than 150 variables in the newdata argument in the tslm model.

Please suggest me a way of doing it.

I have tried this. But I don't think this is a practical process. Can someone suggest me a simple and smaller way of doing it?

// To convert 151 variables in the dataframe to time series

```
x <- 1:151
for(i in seq_along(x)){
y<-ts(data[,i])
  assign(paste('X',i,sep=''),y)
}
```

// I get 151 time series objects as X1,X2 .. X151 .. This step is fine.

// model building
**`fit<-tslm(X1~trend+X2+X3+ ........ + X151)`
// Please suggest me a simple way of doing it, because it doesn't make sense to manually write all 150 variables.. and actually the number of variables may increase**

// forecasting

**fcast<-`forecast(fit,newdata=data.frame(X2=newframe$Temperature,X3=newframe$Inflation, .................................. till 150 variables))`
Please suggest a way of shortening this code too.
Note: "newframe" is the forecasting dataframe**

Comment: Try `tslm(X1 ~., data = yourdata)` for the first part. There are a number of ways to create a data.frame with (many) columns.

Comment: X1 is ts(time series) object. We can't apply tslm(X1 ~., data = yourdata) directly here... Many such ways are available when we use lm() .. the same rules don't apply on tslm()

Answer (score -1):

I am a bit confused regarding your question. Is it 150 different covariates which you are including as regressors, or 150 values as in rows. If they are 150 different covariates and each covariate is a time series, then use the time series for building the model, as you have mentioned

```
    fit<-tslm(X1~trend+X2+X3+ ........ + X151)
```

For forecasting you dont have to explicitly convert into a data frame, simply use the below command,

```
    fcast<-forecast(fit,newdata=data.frame(X2=X2_f,X3=X3_f, .................................. till 150 variables))
```

where X2_f,X3_f are all time series containing the values in the forecast period.

If there are 150 different covariates, it has to be included manually.
But in case, there are 150 different values for a single covariate, it can be directly included as

```
    fit<-tslm(X1~trend+X2)
```

, where X2 is a time series containing the 150 values
and for forecasting

```
fcast<-forecast(fit,newdata=data.frame(X2=X2_f)
```

where X2_f is the time series with the forecasted values.

Hope this helps.